# Concerning the form of a Linear Functional

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $V$ is finite dimensional and $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ is a basis for $V$ and $\phi_1,\phi_2,...,\phi_n$ is the corresponding basis for $V'$ ( the dual space of $V$ ) where $\psi\in V'$ then 
$$\psi = \psi(v_1)\phi_1+\psi(v_2)\phi_2+...+\psi(v_n)\phi_n\tag{1}$$

**Proof.**  Since every linear functional in $V'$ can be expressed as 
 a linear combination of $\phi_1,\phi_2,...,\phi_n$ then in particular for $\psi$ we have 
$$\psi = \alpha_1\phi_1+\alpha_2\phi_2+...+\alpha_n\phi_n\tag{2}$$

Computing the image of $v_j$ under $\psi$ where $j\in\{1,2,3...,n\}$ we see that $\psi(v_j) = \alpha_j\phi(v_j) = \alpha_j$ consequently we may restate $(2)$ as $(1)$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Everything looks good to me.

Comment: It's just fine.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Which part did you think might be incorrect?

Comment: I know the result is quite easy i just wanted to see if it was right since i am new to linear functionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer I've ever posted here:

***YES!!!***